# SQL+ Data Type Currency

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I am learning about SQL+. I am using W3 school for help and tutorials but I ran into a problem. Here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp at the bottom for currency its shows N/A. As I am using SQL+ is this possible to do? Is SQL+ the same as mySQL? Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is not a DBMS product (and w3schools is full of errors and non-standard stuff without clearly stating to which DBMS the non-standard syntax belongs)

Comment: From everything I've heard, @a_horse_with_no_name's assessment of W3School's SQL tutorials is correct.  They're out of date at best and just incorrect at worst.  Oracle's dialect is SQL+ or SQL*Plus.  MySQL's dialect is just MySQL.

Comment: @BaconBits: Oracle's SQL dialect is just "SQL". It doesn't have a special name (as e.g. T-SQL for SQL Server). SQL*Plus is a client tool. And PL/SQL is **only** for stored procedures. It's a procedural language not a query language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SQL*plus (if you meant that) is Oracle technology so "Oracle" would be the correct column for you.

Comment: In the Oracle collom it says N/A. Does this mean you cant do it as currency?